# Freelancing in the Netherlands when residing there with a work permit

Tags: working-visas, netherlands, freelance

In the Netherlands, there are separate visas for freelancers and employees of other companies.  As I understand it one is only allowed to work for the company which has the employee permit for the employee with the permit.

Is it possible to freelance on such a visa?  Is it possible to get, concurrently, a work permit sponsored by an employer and a freelance visa?  Or is a work permit sufficient for freelancing?

Comment: Relevant webpages: http://www.rijksoverheid.nl/onderwerpen/buitenlandse-werknemers/tewerkstellingsvergunning-voor-buitenlandse-werknemers and http://www.antwoordvoorbedrijven.nl/regel/tewerkstellingsvergunning-zzp

Comment: I wasn't able to find a definitive answer but all this and other things I have read suggests that it is *not* possible to freelance on the side.

Comment: Note that most of the documentation available online seems to be about freelancing for Dutch clients. I have no idea how it works if your clients are abroad and you just want to spend some time in the Netherlands while working remotely.

Answer (score 2):

A similar question was asked before. Please see my answer [here](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/a/11438/12182).

In principle, since March 2017 students, highly skilled migrants, and scientific researchers are given more room as entrepreneurs. Please see the linked answer for details.