# More than one job/type of work as EU citizen in the Netherlands

Tags: eu-citizens, netherlands, job-hunting

I'm going to move to the Netherlands. I have a full-time working contract valid 1 year. I will not be able to join the "Higly skilled migrant" scheme.

Is it possible for me to also work as a freelancer?

Comment: What will be your status then? And what's your citizenship (since you mention the highly skilled migrant scheme I assume it means you're from outside the EU and the exact country probably doesn't matter but it's best to be specific).

Comment: See also http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/160/combining-freelance-work-with-kennismigrant-work-permit-in-netherlands?rq=1 (I know you won't be a highly skilled migrant but if it's not possible under this generally more lenient status and switching to a self-employed status is difficult for an highly skilled American, I assume it would be even more difficult in your case).

Comment: Unless you come from Croatia, you can do pretty much whatever you want as EU citizen, what's your concern?

Comment: Please [edit] your country of origin/nationality into your question.

Comment: “not be able” is a strange way to put it, EU citizens enjoy much more favorable rules.

Answer (score 2):

As EU citizen (except if you come from Croatia, for the time being), you are in principle allowed to take on any job you like anywhere in the EU and also to freelance on a par with locals (with a few restrictions for sensitive jobs, e.g. in the military and sometimes some complications to have your credentials recognised if yours is a regulated profession). You [do not need a work permit](http://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/work/work-abroad/work-permits/index_en.htm) and should [be treated like native workers](http://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/work/work-abroad/equal-treatment-with-nationals/index_en.htm).

In principle, EU countries can ask EU citizens to leave if they don't work and don't have financial resources but that's not an issue for you as you do have a job (see [Moving to Germany with fiancée (both EU citizens) because of work reasons. What if she does not find a job?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/3004/moving-to-germany-with-fianc%C3%A9e-both-eu-citizens-because-of-work-reasons-what), [US Citizen with EU Spouse who doesn't yet have a job](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/6056/us-citizen-with-eu-spouse-who-doesnt-yet-have-a-job?rq=1) and [this answer on the politics website](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/1013/what-does-european-union-freedom-of-movement-mean-and-how-much-can-individual/4965#4965) for more). If you will, you need a job to have a right to reside but you don't need anything to have a right to work or freelance.

Comment: Perfect. Because if i would go there as a Higly skilled migrant, i read that i wouldnt be able to work also as a freelancer.

Comment: @ADiEmme Why even consider this? Things like the highly skilled migrant scheme are for third-country (non-EU) citizens, as EU citizen you enjoy much more extensive rights under the EU freedom of movement rules. I assume the Dutch authorities would simply refuse any application for a MVV or Kennismigrant permit because you simply don't need one.